# What are SPF records and how are they related to emails?

Tags: email, spf

I changed the hosting of a website and their email is hosted with another company. There is also an SPF record for that host.

What is the function of that SPF record?

Answer (score 12):

SPF Stands for Sender Policy Framework.  What it allows an administrator to do is specify what servers or internet hosts are allowed to send mail originating from that domain.  See this article for more information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework

Comment: +1 for a clear and concise answer.

Comment: if user are not receiving the emails o their end. Does it has anything to do with SPF

Comment: It's "possible" but it would have to meet some specific circumstances.  If there are SPF entries in DNS that do not match the host name of the server you are sending mail from some mail servers will think that your email is spam and throw it away.  Hotmail for example is not a big fan of invalid SPF entries.

Answer (score 3):

Sender Policy Framework.  It's a method of using DNS TXT records in order to reduce SPAM mail.  The receiving email server needs to read these records.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework

Comment: +1 for posting moments before I did and linking to the same wiki entry :)